# Loading data from API into a highcharts vue component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, highcharts

I'm trying to load data from an express api into my highcharts-vue component, and i'm having trouble with parsing the data into my chart. Express lets me know that my vue component is making a GET request to the API, Postman lets me know the GET request returns an array of date and env_light values but Vue is seemingly not loading, or not updating my chart with the new data

ChartDisplay.vue (component)

```
<template>
  <div class="chartElem">
    <div class="row">
      <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'ChartDisplay',
  components: { highcharts: Chart },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Environment - Light',
        },
        series: [{
          data: [],
          color: '#6fcd98',
        }],
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fillData();
  },
  methods: {
    async fillData() {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/db/env_light')
        .then((response) => {
          this.chartOptions.series[0].data = response.data.map((m) => m.env_light);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The fillData function works as expected when i test it isolated outside of the Vue app and returns an array of values to this.chartOptions.series[0].data, and the chart works and updates automatically if i insert values manually into the data array and save the file.

I've also tried to purge my database from 300+ entries to 5, in case there was a array length issue, and i've tried to parse the data into a structure like this - both unsuccessful

```
.then((response) => {
  this.chartOptions = {
    series: [{
      data: response.data.map((m) => m.env_light),
    }],
  };
});
```

Because the app is making a get request to the API when i refresh sites i know that the fillData method is being executed, and because the app is actually updating changes when i manually insert values into the arary it leads me to believe the default update mechanism for the chart is working. Is there still something wrong with how i parse the data? This is my first Vue app, so i'm a bit puzzled and short on ideas both for solutions or how to further research the issue - any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the problem on Code Sandbox, or Stackblitz? It should be better to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `series` is an array and not an object. So, you are accessing the `data` property of the array containing objects instead of the object itself. What you actually want is to access the `data` property of the first element of the `series` array.

```
this.chartOptions.series[0].data = ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I still can't get the data to load into my graph even with these changes, details on further steps i've taken in post edit